# Angular & Rxjs: How to map json to object array in a function returning Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, nestjs

I share `hero.service.ts` that I used in my project.

```
// hero.service.ts 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/heroes';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
  
      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead
  
      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
  
      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
}

// hero.ts
export interface Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}


// heroes.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
    
  }

  getHeros(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeros();
  }

}
```

When I check the `heroesUrl(http://localhost:3000/heroes)` using Get method in Postman, it returns

```
[
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
]
```

But in my code, I can't get the desired result. What is wrong in my code?
I am finding right answer all day, but I can't find what I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uED4O.png)

I added `heroes.components.ts` file in description.
And `catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))` this part generates `undefined`.
As I used Nestjs as backend, I tried to use `app.enableCors()` to enable all CORS, but it is same the result.
Thanks for your all comments.

Comment: Please check whether it's `CORS` issue through inspect your code?

Comment: Where does it say `undefined`? How is this segment used?

Comment: Information is missing, share the code where you actually call the getHeroes() function.

Comment: I think that should be `catchError(err=>this.handleError<Hero[]>(('getHeroes', [],error)` but I can imagine what is happened

Comment: Thank you, guys. It was CORs problem. I used Nestjs server and I added app.enableCors(); in main.ts as guided in https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors
It's simple solution.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue. It was CORS error.
I used Nestjs server and I added the following code in main.ts

```
app.enableCors();
```

It is simple.
Thank you.